# Populating dropdownlists through LINQ based on a selection from another dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, linq

I have been working on this and it works. However after attempting to change my option from the controlling dropdownlist to see another list in the dropdown that should show my dynamic list, nothing happens. It still shows the previous list. Could i get some help with this?:

Here is my Front side:

```
         <label for="ddlGift1">Gift #1</label>
         <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlGift1" class="gift" AutoPostBack="true"  AppendDataBoundItems="True" ClientIDMode="Static" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlGift1_SelectedIndexChanged"> 
             <asp:ListItem Value="--" Text="Please Select" />
         </asp:DropDownList>  

         <label for="ddlFName1">Fund Name</label>
         <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlFName1" AutoPostBack="true"  AppendDataBoundItems="True" ClientIDMode="Static"  > 
             <asp:ListItem Value="--" Text="Please Select" />
         </asp:DropDownList>


         <label for="ddlGift2">Gift #2</label>
         <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlGift2" class="gift" AutoPostBack="true"  AppendDataBoundItems="True" ClientIDMode="Static" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlGift2_SelectedIndexChanged" > 
             <asp:ListItem Value="--" Text="Please Select" />
         </asp:DropDownList>   

         <label for="ddlFName2">Fund Name</label>
         <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlFName2" AutoPostBack="true"  AppendDataBoundItems="True" ClientIDMode="Static" > 

         <label for="txtPAmount2">Pledge Amount</label>
         <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtPAmount2" CssClass="narrow"  text="0.00" onClick="ComputeCosts();" ClientIDMode="Static" class="PAmount" />             

         <label for="ddlGift3">Gift #3</label>
         <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlGift3" class="gift" AutoPostBack="true"  AppendDataBoundItems="True" ClientIDMode="Static" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlGift3_SelectedIndexChanged"> 
             <asp:ListItem Value="--" Text="Please Select" />
         </asp:DropDownList>  

         <label for="ddlFName3">Fund Name</label>
         <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlFName3" AutoPostBack="true"  AppendDataBoundItems="True" ClientIDMode="Static" > 
             <asp:ListItem Value="--" Text="Please Select" />
         </asp:DropDownList>
```

Backside:
Example of one function:

```
private void SetCOB(DropDownList name)
      {
           var _db = (from a in _foundation.COB
                     orderby a.id
                     select new { a.id, a.name });

        name.DataSource = _db;
        name.DataTextField = "name";
        name.DataValueField = "id";
        name.DataBind();
     }
 protected void ddlGift1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(ddlGift1.SelectedValue == "41")
        {
            SetCOB(ddlFName1);
        }
        else if (ddlGift1.SelectedValue == "42")
        {
            SetCOLA(ddlFName1);
        }
        else if (ddlGift1.SelectedValue == "43")
        {
            SetCONHP(ddlFName1);
        }
        else if (ddlGift1.SelectedValue == "44")
        {
            SetOE(ddlFName1);
        }
        else if (ddlGift1.SelectedValue == "45")
        {
            SetCSEE(ddlFName1);
        }
        else if (ddlGift1.SelectedValue == "52")
        {
            SetA(ddlFName1);
        }
        else if (ddlGift1.SelectedValue == "54")
        {
            SetS(ddlFName1);
        }
    }

    protected void ddlGift2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ddlGift2.SelectedValue == "41")
        {
            SetCOB(ddlFName2);
        }
        else if (ddlGift2.SelectedValue == "42")
        {
            SetCOLA(ddlFName2);
        }
        else if (ddlGift2.SelectedValue == "43")
        {
            SetCONHP(ddlFName2);
        }
        else if (ddlGift2.SelectedValue == "44")
        {
            SetOE(ddlFName2);
        }
        else if (ddlGift2.SelectedValue == "45")
        {
            SetCSEE(ddlFName2);
        }
        else if (ddlGift2.SelectedValue == "52")
        {
            SetA(ddlFName2);
        }
        else if (ddlGift2.SelectedValue == "54")
        {
            SetS(ddlFName2);
        }
    }

    protected void ddlGift3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ddlGift3.SelectedValue == "41")
        {
            SetCOB(ddlFName3);
        }
        else if (ddlGift3.SelectedValue == "42")
        {
            SetCOLA(ddlFName3);
        }
        else if (ddlGift3.SelectedValue == "43")
        {
            SetCONHP(ddlFName3);
        }
        else if (ddlGift3.SelectedValue == "44")
        {
            SetOE(ddlFName3);
        }
        else if (ddlGift3.SelectedValue == "45")
        {
            SetCSEE(ddlFName3);
        }
        else if (ddlGift3.SelectedValue == "52")
        {
            SetA(ddlFName3);
        }
        else if (ddlGift3.SelectedValue == "54")
        {
            SetS(ddlFName3);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `SetCOB` method need to query based on dropdownlist's selected value. Currently, it is querying all.

It should be something like this -

```
protected void ddlGift1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(ddlGift1.SelectedValue == "41")
    {
       SetCOB(41, ddlFName1);
    }
    .....
}

private void SetCOB(int id, DropDownList name)
{
    var _db = (from a in _foundation.COB
       where a.id == id 
      orderby a.id
      select new { a.id, a.name });
    .....
}
```

Comment: Gift's list is different from COB. It is pretty much a sublist of items based on what was selected in Gift.  So in this case passing 41 to COB wouldnt do much since the 41 in gift isnt related to the 41 what is in COB

Comment: I'm not familiar with your code. Basically, once you select a dropdownlist, pass that selected value to next dropdownlist's datasource which queries based on that selected value. I do not see that in your code - it is why you are always seeing `It still shows the previous list. `.

Comment: But all the drop down lists are different. Gift being the main drop downlist is the only one with an item id of 41. The fund drop downlist is the one i want to change not the gift

Comment: I really want to help, but I don't know what ddls depends on what. Instead of having multiple methods (SetCOB, SetCOLA, ...), (as a good design practice) please create a single method with a (int or enum) parameter and differentiate based on that parameter.

Comment: is there a way to remove the options from a list like i added them?

Comment: You can use `ddl1.Items.Clear()` to clear all item in the list. Then re-add them back. OR `ListItem item = ddl1.Items.FindByValue("41"); ddl1.Items.Remove(item);`

Answer (score 0):

By using LINQ you can make conditional selection of the second drop down list data source, like in this example which shows city based on selected country using Linq query:

**The HTML ASP.Net**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style>
        .required:after {
            content: " * ";
            font-weight: bold;
            color: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Country:</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCountries" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
                            OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCountries_SelectedIndexChanged">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>City:</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCities" runat="server">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**The Code Behind in C#**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using WebApplication2.Models;

namespace WebApplication2
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                GetData();

            }
        }

        private List<City> SetCityData()
        {
            List<City> cities = new List<City>()
            {
                new City() { Id = 1, CountryId = 2, CityName = "Amman"  },
                new City() { Id = 1, CountryId = 2, CityName = "Zarqa"  },
                new City() { Id = 1, CountryId = 4, CityName = "Istanbul"  },
                new City() { Id = 1, CountryId = 4, CityName = "Ankara"  },
                new City() { Id = 1, CountryId = 4, CityName = "Mersin"  },
                new City() { Id = 1, CountryId = 4, CityName = "Trabzon"  },
                new City() { Id = 1, CountryId = 1, CityName = "Rio de Janeiro"  },
                new City() { Id = 1, CountryId = 3, CityName = "Los Angeles"  },
                new City() { Id = 1, CountryId = 3, CityName = "Chicago"  },
            };
            return cities;
        }

        protected void ddlCountries_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int selectedCountry = Convert.ToInt32(ddlCountries.SelectedValue);
            var cityByCountry = from c in SetCityData()
                                where c.CountryId == selectedCountry
                                select c;
            ddlCities.DataSource = cityByCountry.ToList();
            ddlCities.DataTextField = "CityName";
            ddlCities.DataValueField = "Id";
            ddlCities.DataBind();
        }

        private List<Country> SetCountries()
        {
            List<Country> countries = new List<Country>()
            {
                new Country() { Id = 1, CountryName = "Brazil"  },
                new Country() { Id = 2, CountryName = "Jordan" },
                new Country() { Id = 3, CountryName = "USA" },
                new Country() { Id = 4, CountryName = "Turkey" }
            };
            return countries;
        }

        private void GetData()
        {
            ddlCountries.DataSource = SetCountries();
            ddlCountries.DataTextField = "CountryName";
            ddlCountries.DataValueField = "Id";
            ddlCountries.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

**The Country and City Classes**

```
using System;

namespace WebApplication2.Models
{
    public class Country
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string CountryName { get; set; }
    }
}

using System;

namespace WebApplication2.Models
{
    public class City
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int CountryId { get; set; }
        public string CityName { get; set; }

    }
}
```